# Disable XF86Back and XF86Forward (browser back/forward on Lenovo Thinkpad)

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, lenovo

My Thinkpad R500 has back/forward keys just about the direction keys, so on Firefox I keep losing entered text, accidentally.

How to disable these back/forward keys?

Excerpt from xev:

```
KeyPress event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0xbc, subw 0x0, time 2375874, (1279,794), root:(1285,881),
    state 0x10, keycode 166 (keysym 0x1008ff26, XF86Back), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0xbc, subw 0x0, time 2377115, (1279,794), root:(1285,881),
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can disable keys using the [`xmodmap`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html) command. For example, to disable `XF86Back`, run the following command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 166="
```

This sets the keycode `166` (Which is the keycode for `XF86Back` as you can see in the `xev` output) to nothing, which means it is disabled.
To re-enable `XF86Back`:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 166=XF86Back"
```

To disable both the Back and Forward keys automatically, create the file `.xmodmap` in your home folder and paste the following inside it:

```
keycode 166=
keycode 167=
```

Comment: Works great :-)

Comment: I could also suggest you to sue them as Home and End keys. This works great for text editing on my ThinkPad. Simply set the keycode equal to `Home` and `End`.

Comment: This works on my ThinkPad X220 too.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rasmus: "sue them" haha "use them" I guess ;-) Yes, this makes a lot of sense and is useful under vim or terminal as well. To make sure everyone understands, it is `keycode 166=Home` and `keycode 167=End`.

Comment: How can I map them to do something like ctrl+right_arrow?

Comment: xmodmap -e "keycode 166=" works perfectly, but when I add the file .xmodmap with the contents to my home the back and forward still working. am I missing something here?

Comment: @Husni: same here. Looks like the name varies. On some systems it's .xmodmaprc, on Ubuntu it appears to be .Xmodmap since oneiric.

Comment: Unfortunately, .xmodmap home files do not work with recent versions of Ubuntu (it doesn't matter what name you use), see http://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04 .  If anyone can give comprehensible instructions on how to disable these keys with XKB that would be great.