# How to apply Xmodmap permanently

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I had to make some changes to the xmodmap in my home directory. When I execute `xmodmap ./.Xmodmap` everything works as expected. But I can't figure out how to apply this permanently. I tried to add it to a file called `.xinitrc` like suggested in other questions here but it's just not working.

My system is freshly installed 13.04 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use gnome-session-properties (in the Dash can be found by typing Startup - it will find the Startup Applications Preferences application:

see:

[image: screenshot]

Then add a new command for xmodmap. Use the absolute path to the file you want to launch with xmodmap:

see:

[image: screenshot]

You can also switch back to a “normal” layout using: `setxkbmap -layout fr` (replace “fr” with “us” or your keyboard layout variant).

Comment: That sounds promising but theres no program found in the dash typing Startup...

Comment: If the interface is in another language, you might not find the brogram through the Dash. Please try to launch the app by typing its name, `gnome-session-properties` from a Terminal window.

Comment: Id used the program to configure the way you suggested but it does not work. It does not seem to execute the program at all. Will this be executed on each login or do i have to reboot the machine?

Comment: A reboot should not be necessary but a log out is required to see if it works. Also, please check that the command works from the Terminal and that the path to the .Xmodmap file is complete (something like `/home/yourusername/.Xmodmap`). As a last resort, you can look just after logging in in the system log file: `/var/log/syslog` for any kind of encountered errors.

Comment: Still not working, no errors occured in the syslog. This is driving me nuts... it used to be so easy. .Xmodmap in the home directory has been read automaticly before... why did they make ubuntu stopping this? Is there maybe a new way this can be configured?

Comment: Today I learned about `gnome-session-properties`! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Any changes to the key bindings using xmodmap or xkb will be trampled if you suspend or change keymap. Also, on login, they won't work in the first few seconds (since GNOME will load its own keymap later).

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/514277) for details and a few workarounds; personally I'm using [dedalu's script](https://askubuntu.com/a/514277/99932).