# how to disable the up and down arrow keys on my laptop

Tags: 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

I ran the code `xev -event` keyboard on my terminal, after that I entered code `xmodmap -e 'keycode 113='` ; but my up arrow key was not disabled as I expected.

I repeated the same procedure for the other key(down arrow key) but this time I changed the 113 to 116 hoping to disable the down arrow key but it was not disabled.

[image]

Comment: Until you get it configured, pit a piece of scotch tape on each keycap you want to nullify. The texture will teach you to stop touching them quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
xev -event keyboard
```

a line from above command output for Up Arrow  key
`state 0x10, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,`

a line from above command output  for Down Arrow key
`state 0x10, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,`

Run below commands

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = "
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 116 = "
$
```

Check with below commands

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep Up
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode 151 = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp
keycode 185 = XF86ScrollUp NoSymbol XF86ScrollUp NoSymbol XF86ScrollUp
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
$ xmodmap -pke | grep Down
keycode  88 = KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2
keycode 186 = XF86ScrollDown NoSymbol XF86ScrollDown NoSymbol XF86ScrollDown
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 237 = XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown
$
```

`xev -event keyboard` result

```
KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x105, subw 0x0, time 396765, (1224,931), root:(1274,1011),
    state 0x10, keycode 111 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x105, subw 0x0, time 397693, (1224,931), root:(1274,1011),
    state 0x10, keycode 116 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: The up and down arrow keys of my system is faulty and keep pressing, can this prevent the code  xev -event keyboard and 
state 0x10, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES from running well?

Comment: In that case, Just run `xmodmp -pke | grep Up` to know the keycode. same way for Down also.. then `xmodmap -e "keycode $UpValue = "` same way `xmodmap -e "keycode $DownValue = "`

Comment: Is there a permanent solution for this? This method works, until restarting

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/333897/how-to-apply-xmodmap-permanently can you try this?