# Map Pause button for Volume Up and Scroll_Lock for Volume Down

Tags: keyboard, volume-control

I have the volume keys on the keyboard as <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> respectively.

I would like to map the <kbd>Pause</kbd> button to volume up and <kbd>SCRLK</kbd> as volume down since those two buttons are useless anyway.

I tried `setkeycodes XF86AudioRaiseVolume 0xff13` but it didn't work.

Is this doable? This is for an USB keyboard for my desktop.

Comment: Hi.. What is your OS and Can you share a link to your keyboard pic or model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Example on Ubuntu 19.10***

1. Open Gnome-Terminal
2. Run `xev | grep keycode`
3. Press <kbd>SCRLK</kbd> key once and <kbd>Pause</kbd> key once

you will have the result like this

```
$ xev | grep keycode
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 78 (keysym 0xff14, Scroll_Lock), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 78 (keysym 0xff14, Scroll_Lock), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 127 (keysym 0xff13, Pause), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 127 (keysym 0xff13, Pause), same_screen YES,
$
```

4. Note down the keycode for <kbd>SCRLK</kbd> and <kbd>Pause</kbd> 78 and 127 in my case.
5. now run `xmodmap -e "keycode 78 = XF86AudioLowerVolume"`
6. `xmodmap -e "keycode 127 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume"`

sample:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 78 = XF86AudioLowerVolume"
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 127 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume"
$
```

Once you logout above changes will reset to normal..

There are different ways to make `xmodmap` changes permanently.. a google search will give you lot of links.. one of them is [How to apply Xmodmap permanently](https://askubuntu.com/q/333897/739431)

Comment: It worked. Thank you, I did so much googling, didn't think it would be so easy, all in one line. My keycodes were the same so I didn't need to change anything.