# Cannot disable `Tools` keybinding on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04, and was trying to reassign some of the keybindings. On my keyboard (Das Keyboard 4, mac) there is a "F13" button, which is seen as `Tools` on Ubuntu. On 18.04 I just simply disabled it, but on 20.04 this button still opens the settings menu. I wonder if there is a way to "force-forget" this keybinding?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

[image: Tools|Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in Ubuntu 20.04, where it would unset the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys control-center`, but not the static version of it:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i control-center
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys control-center ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys control-center-static ['XF86Tools']
```

I am not sure if this is because it's a `XF86*` key, or because it fails to change both dconf settings. Either way, the solution is (supposed to be) to manually reset it:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys control-center-static "['']"
```

However, in my case this solution didn't work, and I had to do it through the `dconf-editor`, which worked:

```
$ sudo apt install dconf-editor
$ dconf-editor
```

After that change the appropriate settings in the GUI:

[image]

Comment: In Fedora 39/Gnome 45, dconf-editor doesn't show me the `control-center-static` key at all. But I ran `sudo dconf update` after the `gsettings ...` command and the keybinding is finally gone.