# How do I remap my Tab key on startup? - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, remapping

My tab key doesn't work properly, so I'm trying to remap it to the grave/tilde key right above it. I have already found out the command to map it -

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = Tab"
```

but it reverts back to the original when I restart my computer. How do I stop this from happening? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/333897/739431

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply Xmodmap permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333897/how-to-apply-xmodmap-permanently)

Comment: I found this the easiest way to get it done - [https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-can-i-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04/1161870#1161870](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-can-i-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04/1161870#1161870)