# How do I make a program auto-start everytime I log in in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, startup-applications

I read the previous answers to this question, and tried to follow, but it does not work. I wanted to add Chromium and Skype to the Startup Applications, but I can't find out what command I should write in there. 
I tried the other suggested method: right-clicked on the icon in the Launcher, but there is no item called "Add to the Startup" in the pop-up menu.
I am new to Linux and Ubuntu, sorry if there is an obvious answer, please help.
Thanks
Peter

Comment: Added a simple script to find (all) applications and their commands to the existing duplicate http://askubuntu.com/a/459498/72216

Answer (score 21):

Press `Super(Win)Key` and type **Startup applications**:

[image]

[image]

Click **Add**.

[image]

Click **Add**.

This was for **Chromium Browser**. Now, for **Skype**,

**Name :** `Skype`

**Command :** `skype --pipelogin`

Then Click **Add**.

You can manually add scripts or command in desktop files [[Desktop Entry]](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) and put them in `~/.config/autostart/blah.desktop`