# Adding Skype to start-up programs

Tags: 14.04, startup, startup-applications

I use the command below to automatically open and sign in Skype from a terminal:

```
$echo myusername mypassword | skype --pipelogin
```

But when I put the exact command in Startup Apllications...nothing happens when I login in to Ubuntu (Unity).

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you use the built in setting "Automatic startup" of Skype, it does not work ?

Comment: @hg8 There is no option like that :(

Comment: If you go in Skype > Options > Start Skype minimized in the system tray ?

Comment: @hg8 That option is for when the Skype starts....the skype should start first then that option makes it to go minimized....the problem here is how to actually start skype when user logs in Ubuntu after a reboot or re-login

Comment: Right sorry, I tough this started Skype too. Why don't you just put 'skype' in Startup Application ?

Comment: possibly duplicate of this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/459277/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Why did you accept Harris' answer over mine? You asked how to get it to startup on startup, and then auto-log you in, however Harris' answer only covers the starting up on start business, when mine covers all of that. So why did you find his answer better than mine?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda don't be paranoid :D there ya go

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make Skype auto-login when it starts launch Skype, then login with the automatic login tick box selected (I have highlighted the bit which you will need to tick in the bottom right hand corner):

[image]

After you have completed that part, you can then do as [@Harris](https://askubuntu.com/a/663390/364819)  says to make Skype launch automatically when you login:

Move your `skype.desktop` file into your autostart folder with:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

And you shouldn't need to make the `skype.desktop` file executable for it to work.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18, there is no such file...

Answer (score 10):

My solution is the following. Start the terminal and copy the file `skype.desktop` into `~/.config/autostart` folder, using:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

And make it executable: (this step was necessary in my system but people reported it is not required)

```
chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/skype.desktop
```

That should start skype everytime you login. I hope it helps.

Comment: `chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/skype.desktop` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In SkyPe Beta, there is an option to launch at login

*Tools > Launch at Login*

[image]