# How can I add screensaver to startup applications?

Tags: xscreensaver

How do I add a screensaver to the startup application? I have used this command:

```
xscreensaver -no-splash
```

What am I doing wrong or not doing? I am using the latest Ubuntu version.

Comment: There is no need to do this in Ubuntu. In Settings - Power, you will find build-in options to save the screen. See here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/663370/adding-skype-to-start-up-programs) how, in general, one can add to the startup programs.

Comment: @vanadium `xscreensaver` is a separate application that requires removal of `gnome-screensaver` to function properly.

Comment: @vanadium you might consider posting an answer here :)

Answer (score 1):

`xscreensaver` used to be the default screen saver in gnome and unity. A few years ago gnome came out with "environmentally friendly" screen saver that turns the screen black. Subsequently they broke xscreensaver with all it's fancy screen effects.

To use xscreensaver you must remove gnome-screensaver. From:

- [How to Install, Change, Autostart Screensaver in Ubuntu](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/08/install-change-autostart-setup-screensaver-ubuntu-linux/)

To summarize the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
xscreensaver -nosplash
```

Visit the link for screenshots and instructions of adding to autostart.

Also note after upgrades you may have to remove `gnome-screensaver` again.