# xbindkeys + xdotool or xvkbd not working well

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xdotool, xbindkeys

In my `.xbindkeysrc` I'm trying to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow key.

`xvkbd` works okay in some places, but doesn't send anything at all in the terminal. For example:

```
"xvkbd  -xsendevent -text "\[Up]""
    Alt + l
```

`xdotool` works in the terminal, but only sends the <kbd>Up</kbd> key once, because I had to add `+ Release`, otherwise it triggers too early or something and always sends nothing:

```
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers Up"
    Alt + l + Release
```

Neither of these solutions are very good. I just want <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>;</kbd> to be arrow keys while <kbd>Alt</kbd> is held down.

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: @Xubu-Tur I've swapped keys with `xmodmap` np, the problem with that though is I can't swap keys ONLY while alt is down.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"xset r off; xdotool keyup --window 0 l key --window 0 --clearmodifiers Up; xset r on"
    Alt + l
```

Comment: but if you hold alt+l it only gets pressed once