# Disable power-off button on NVidia Shield controller (joystick) in Unity

Tags: unity, nvidia, shortcut-keys, joystick

I have an NVidia Shield Controller, that is detected by Ubuntu as a standard joystick. Unity seems to react to some of the special buttons of this controller such as Volume Up, Volume Down and more annoyingly a special button on the controller is mapped to XF86PowerOff.

I know that the buttons is mapped to the keycode 124 thanks to `xinput`.

```
$ xinput test 'NVIDIA Corporation NVIDIA Controller v01.03'
key press   124
```

I also know that the keycode 124 is mapped to XF86PowerOff thanks to:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 124
keycode 124 = XF86PowerOff ...
```

I would like to disable this button but it doesn't seem to work using something like:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 124 ="
```

I just want to use the joystick in a dedicated app, I don't need Unity to do anything special with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should work for you, just be sure to credit them if it works. (but send me a note or something!) [remapping in newer versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)

Comment: Thank you, I haven't been able to test the xkb method (shown here http://askubuntu.com/a/347382/347656) because it's a bit complicated and I didn't want to break the whole system instead of just my user. I no longer have the controller at my disposal but what I did was to disable the keys in dconf database using `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'nothing'` and `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys active 'false'`.