# Change keyboard mapping ONLY for Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, keyboard-layout, xinput, xkb

I have a Bluetooth "Camera Shutter" dongle.  It emulates a Bluetooth keyboard.  I've paired successfully, but I want to change how the buttons behave.

Currently, they're mapped to `123` (Volume Up) and `36` (Enter).

I'd like to change their mappings - but only for *this* Bluetooth keyboard.  I want my laptop's keyboard to be unaffected.

My end goal is to have a Python program run when one of the keys is pressed.

Some things I found which didn't work:

- I don't want to [change the language of the external keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/75817/two-keyboards-on-one-computer-when-i-write-with-a-i-want-a-us-keyboard-layout) using `setxkbmap`.
- Using `xkb` [seems to remap keys on all keyboards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382#347382).
- `xinput` can [remap mouse buttons but not keyboard keys](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input).

I want to press "Volume Up" on my external keyboard and have a command run - without interfering with my internal keyboard's "Volume Up" key.

Any ideas? Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. Thanks.

Comment: [Seems like you figured it out](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2016/02/cheap-bluetooth-buttons-and-linux/), you should post a self-answer!

Answer (score 0):

As per https://superuser.com/a/869064/140864 - it's possible to use `xkbcomp` to change the assignment of specific keys.

```
remote_id=$(
    xinput list |
    sed -n 's/.*AB Shutter 3.*id=\([0-9]*\).*keyboard.*/\1/p'
)
[ "$remote_id" ] || exit

mkdir -p /tmp/xkb/symbols
cat >/tmp/xkb/symbols/custom <<\EOF
xkb_symbols "remote" {
    key <VOL+>  { [ XF86Launch1 ] };
    key <RTRN>  { [ XF86Launch2 ] };
};
EOF

setxkbmap -device $remote_id -print | sed 's/\(xkb_symbols.*\)"/\1+custom(remote)"/' | xkbcomp -I/tmp/xkb -i $remote_id -synch - $DISPLAY 2>/dev/null
```

This needs to be run every time the device is connected.  The keys can then be assigned to a specific shortcut action in Gnome.