# Change Right Alt Key to Page Up Key

Tags: xmodmap

I would like to set the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as a <kbd>Page up</kbd> key.

Currently I have the following set which gets half of what I want done.

```
key <MENU> { [ Next ] };
```

I have tried xmodmap and it doesn't work for reassigning the right <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

Thank you!

Comment: What "menus" are you talking about? The context menu is a collection of choices, you can't set the menu itself to an action.. Unless you mean the right mouse button? And what is the page down "menu"? Have you seen the question here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382#347382

Comment: @Seth thank you I do not have my ubuntu station with me currently.  It appears that might work.  I reworded the question because it was confusing it now says "I would like to set the context menu as a page down key."

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not answer my question. The context menu is a collection of menu choices, it does not make sense when you say "set the context menu as a page down key". Is there any other way you could explain what you mean to do?

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of Ubuntu, Xmodmap works but after you reboot, you lose your keymappings! Instead what I did was to edit the xbd file (/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc).

In this case you would add the following entries:

```
key <FK09> { [Print] };
key <FK10> { [Scroll_Lock] };
```

Then clear the xkb settings cache:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

After a reboot your keys are mapped corectly. If you need more help with this see my post on [remapping keys in Ubuntu 15.04](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/howto/remap-keyboard-keys-for-ubuntu/)

Comment: you forgot `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*`  also is there any way to get it to take effect without rebooting?