# Issue with multiple keymaps when wake from suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, xmodmap, resume

Trying to xmodmap this file .Xmodmap upon resume. Tried [how to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend) by adding multiple key mappings using xmodmap -e without success (each time it would only accept the first line). I feel it should be able to use .Xmodmap to keep the code simple. Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you.

My .Xmodmap (with executable permission) in /home/dadtwo/

```
clear control
clear mod4

keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

add control = Control_L
add mod4 = Super_L
```

My 10_keyboard-swap (with executable permission) located in /etc/pm/sleep.d

```
#!/bin/sh

# Remap Swap Super_L and Control_L

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
    DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
    su $dadtwo -c "sleep 3; /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/dadtwo/.Xmodmap"&
;;
esac
```

/var/log/pm-suspend.log says "/usr/bin/xmodmap:  unable to open display ':0.0'"

Comment: Try: Change the name, so it happens later in the sequence, e.g. `50_keyboard-swap`. See `man run-parts`

Comment: @waltinator changed to 50, still unable to open display, no difference. When I change it to a single keyboard map `su $dadtwo -c "sleep 3; /usr/bin/xmodmap -e "clear conrol"" &` It runs without returning any errors, however I could not figure out the syntax on adding additional lines, as contained in my .Xmodmap

Answer (score 0):

`ldd $(type -p xmodmap)` shows that `xmodmap` uses `libX11.so.6` to communicate with the X server. Therefore, one cannot use `xmodmap` before the X server is running.

```
$ ldd $(type -p xmodmap)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc5c1f3000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8abffa6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8abfbe1000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8abf9c2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8abf7be000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8ac02db000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8abf5ba000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8abf3b4000)
```

On my Ubuntu 14.04.5, (YMMV), by using `pgrep X`, and `ps -fp$(pgrep X)` and following the `PPID` field back two steps, I see:

```
$ ps -fp1851,1801,1603
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1603     1  0 Jul27 ?        00:00:00 gdm
root      1801  1603  0 Jul27 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/_0
root      1851  1801  1 Jul27 tty7     04:30:37 /usr/bin/X :0 -background none -verbose -logverbose 7 -core -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-ZKZ4jH/database -seat seat0 -nolisten t
```

Which tells me that the X server (`X`), PID 1851 (on my system, at this time, YMMV) was started by PID 1801 (`/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-simple-slave`), which, in turn, was started by PID 1603 (`gdm`).

`gdm` only starts `gdm-simple-slave` (which starts `X`) AFTER you login, so this won't work before login.

Running `xmodmap` either before `X` is started, or without putting `export DISPLAY=:0` into your script before the `xmodmap`, AND having done `man xhost;xhost +local:` in your X session.

Rephrased answer:

Read `man xhost`.

After you've logged in, open a terminal window and look:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

Allow processes running on this system, but NOT running under the `X` server process to communicate with the `X` server process:

```
$ xhost +local:
non-network local connections being added to access control list
```

This will last until you change it back (`xhost -local:`) OR until the `X` server exits, so, if this works for you, put it in your user startup somewhere.

For as long as `xhost +locakl:` is in effect, you can run your `xmodmap` in any context (e.g. from `/etc/pm/power.d/`) by doing:

```
env DISPLAY=:0 xmodmap ....
```

or, if you want to use multiple `xmodmap` commands,

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xmodmap ...
xmodmap ...
```

Note: Allowing connections to your `X` server by "non-network local connections" DOES make your system less secure.

Comment: not trying to make the system less secure. 1: Are you saying that waking from sleep creates a login process? What I don't understand is how putting the code directly in that line as described here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend] is not functioning. 2: Was the answer provided there wrong? ie. not possible?

Comment: 0. But you are making your system a little less secure. 1. No. That's "not even wrong" See `pstree -a -c -l -p -u 1`. 1.5 Environment variables last the length of the script, then vanish. 2. Not wrong, just incomplete. `X` server must be told to accept requests from outside its' process subtree.

Comment: Could a different approach be used? If I implemented a 10 second delay on the execution of the xmodmap, would it then be inside the x server subtree? Or would it still be outside because I'm calling it from sleep.d?

Comment: Or... is there a way to make the map permanent so it does not revert when going into suspend?

Comment: After some more digging, I found a script by dedalu that runs in the background and initiates xmodmap. What do you think of it? I tested, and is working. [xmodmap python script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/514277#514277)