# Mac canadian multilingual keyboard on ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using the Mac Canadian Multilingual keyboard with Ubuntu 16, shown below. The Canadian Multilingual text entry option works almost fine, but I have the following problems.

1. The <kbd>left alt</kbd> and <kbd>right alt</kbd> are swapped. I have to press on the <kbd>right alt</kbd> key in order to write the brackets `{` and `}` (that makes coding and writing in Latex very difficult).
2. The keys for <kbd>ù</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> are also swapped.

How can I fix this? I tried everything suggested in the related posts on this site (and elsewhere), to no avail.

I tried using an English configuration for my keyboard, only switching to French when necessary, but this makes me waste too much time.

**Note:** This problem is very serious for French-Canadian Ubuntu users. I must keep my MacBook air next to my Ubuntu desktop to write emails and to write in Latex.

**Attempted fixes:**

- Using `xev`, I found that the left alt is keycode 64, registered as Alt_L, right alt is keycode 108, registered as ISO_Level3_Shift. The command `xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = ISO_Level3_Shift"` makes the left alt key unresponsive whitout fixing the problem.
- In the file '/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ca', I swapped the content (what is in the brackets) between the two following lines:

  ```
  key <TLDE>  { [     slash,  backslash,           bar ]  };
  key <LSGT>  { [    ugrave,     Ugrave ]     };
  ```

  While in the file '/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level3' I swapped all appearances of LALT and RALT.

[image]

Comment: The [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382#347382?newreg=4eb097870a15490ebbe39d78412f9797) should help you work out how to remap your keys.  Ensure you're using instruction that use `xkb` and not `xmodmap`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found the file '/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ca' that contains the canadian Multilingual keyboard layout; I'll try to modify it.

Comment: @Dorian: There is no need to edit package owned files in this case. Please see my answer.

Comment: take a look at https://superuser.com/a/1188622/685512 -- does the bug workaround help?

Comment: @quixotic: That shouldn't be needed on Ubuntu due to the `apple:badmap` option.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson except xkb options won't affect virtual console keymaps, that workaround does.  better to understand the root cause when possible.

Comment: @quixotic: It's effective on console if you edit `/etc/default/keyboard`. Please see `man keyboard`. Also, on my 16.10 there is no `/sys/module/hid_apple` folder.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Was just showing a way.  Pretty sure there won't be an update for a while anyways since the project's been frozen for a while now.

Comment: @Dorian: Which project?

Comment: xkb-data package

Comment: @Dorian: `xkeyboard-config` upstream is updated continuously, and it's more likely than not that an upgrade to a new Ubuntu version means an update of `xkb-data`. But yes, a stable release update of `xkb-data` is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing files owned by the `xkb-data` package should be avoided, since the changes will be lost if/when the package is updated. And in this case there is a more straightforward way to achieve what you want.

So, the first thing I suggest is that you reset the changes you made by running this command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data
```

Then you can use XKB options. To change the behavior in the current session you can run this command:

```
setxkbmap -option "lv3:lalt_switch,lv3:ralt_alt,apple:badmap"
```

If that does what you want, you can make the changes persistent by opening the file `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and change this line:

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:lalt_switch,lv3:ralt_alt,apple:badmap"
```

Comment: awesome, didn't know about `apple:badmap`.

Comment: @quixotic: No, unfortunately that option is somewhat hidden. It works in Debian/Ubuntu because of a patch, but not on distros which use the upstream XKB unmodified.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson What if I have 2 keyboards layouts and I switch between them. The swap still occurs. How can I configure only the french canadian one?

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier: Don't know. OTOH, the need to swap  ought to be there irrespective of which layout is active (even if you may not consider those keys important enoght when using the other layout).

Answer (score 0):

**Bad approach** (see the other answer)

To swap the left and right alts, access the file '/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level3':

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level3
```

and swap the character strings `<LALT>` and `<RALT>` everywhere they appear.

To swap the keys corresponding to 'ù' and '/' (for the Canadian Multilingual layout), access the file '/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ca':

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ca
```

and swap the contents (what is between the brackets '[' and ']') of the keys `<TLDE>` and `<LSGT>`

Comment: editing these files is unnecessary, especially not the "swap this everywhere" you recommend for `level3`.  please don't recommend this.  xkb options can be used to override any troublesome keys.