# How to map the AltGr key to the Menu key?

Tags: keyboard, remapping

On my Lenevo T460 laptop keyboard, I'd like to change the value of the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key (between <kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>) to the [<kbd>Menu</kbd> key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) as that is far more applicable for my use.

So far, I've managed to successfully change the <kbd>Home</kbd> & <kbd>End</kbd> keymapping to <kbd>PgUp</kbd> & <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and vice versa following [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/347382/412024) by editing the `xkb` file.

Is there a similar way to change <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to <kbd>Menu</kbd> key as well?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt_Gr</kbd> has the very intuitive name `ISO_Level3_Shift`. Therefore one has to change the following line in the `pc` file as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382#347382) from

```
key <MENU> {    [ Menu  ]   };
```

to

```
key <MENU> {    [ ISO_Level3_Shift  ]   };
```

Comment: Open bounties can't be cancelled. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109922/how-can-i-cancel-bounty-on-my-question.