# No 'Super Key' on IBM Model M keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware, remapping

So I have a IBM Model M keyboard because it is just the best keyboard ever manufactured....

Thus being said I have no 'Super key'. So I am missing a lot basic functionality. So my question is, how do I map the 'Super Key' to another key that isn't frequently used? Maybe like the 'F9' key or something.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanent xmodmap in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: While this may work (I don't know) I believe I found an easier way and will update with an answer later today when I get back to my computer if someone else.doesnt beat me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through the Settings application:

Open Settings: Click on "Keyboard Shortcuts" Search for "Lock"- Click on the only option and set to desired keyboard combination.

[image]