# Change Hyper key from mod 4 to mod 3

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, keys

Is there any way to change this permanently?
I do it with an xmodmap script but I have to run it every time I boot my device (Ubuntu 20.04) and I want to find a way to do it permanently

Comment: The only *viable* option that I've seen for this is [dedalu's script from a few years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/514277/1091774). It still works for 20.04 and newer, though some machines do display a bit of lag as a result.

Comment: I'm actually using this command on startup, and it works for making the CapsLock a Hyper key, the problem i have at the moment is that the "Hyper key" is at the same mod level than the "Super key", so, whenever i press hyper to set up a new shortcut, Ubuntu sees it as a "Super" press, so I want to find a way to change the mod levels permanently, I know there's a way to do it with Xmodmap but like i said, it just doesn't run at startup T_T there must be a way to make it permanent, isn't it? 