# How do ibus-setup, xfce4-keyboard-settings, /usr/share/m17n/, /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols relate to each other?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xfce, ibus

In ancient times it was `~/.Xmodmap`, then I learned how to [tweak keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/a/846184/367444) settings via `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. Now I have

1. ibus-setup fed from /usr/share/m17n/ it seems
2. xfce4-keyboard-settings configured by /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols somehow

and both pretend to set up my keyboard. It seems that I get (2.) at startup but as soon as I use the ibus layout switcher (super space in my case), ibus takes over and my layout tweaks in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols are ignored.

Can someone explain how these two systems play together --- or not? If I only need an English layout with some hand-crafted tweaks on a few keys, may I uninstall ibus? Or should I rely solely on ibus and tweak an ibus layout?

EDIT to clarify what I am doing: I am using a using my own xkb file in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols with the following content

```
default
xkb_symbols "basic" {
  name[Group1] = "Harald Special";
  include "us"
  key <AE10> { [ 0, parenright, degree, NoSymbol] };
  key <AC01> { [ a, A, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis] };
  include "level3(ralt_switch)"
  include "ctrl(nocaps)"
};
```

The filename appears in xfce4-keyboard-settings but not in ibus-setup. As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/846184/367444), I have not tweaked some `evdev.xml`, maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Comment offhand: If you only need XKB layouts, you probably don't need IBus.

OTOH:

> as soon as I use the ibus layout switcher (super space in my case),
> ibus takes over and my layout tweaks in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`
> are ignored

That does not sound plausible to me. `ibus-setup` makes most of the layouts in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` available, and if an XKB layout is correctly tweaked somehow, the tweaks should apply even if you enable the layout via IBus.

Comment: I may indeed have not completely correctly tweaked the XKB layouts. If you could extend the answer so that it answers: "Should my own layout appear in the `ibus-setup` if done properly" that would be great.

Comment: @Harald: Now you are talking about your "own layout", while I was talking about modifications to an existing XKB layout. So possibly we talk past each other. If your concern is about an alternative keyboard layout with a different name, it's a bit more complicated. I'd suggest that you clarify your actual case by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

To make an additional XKB layout, located in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`, available in ibus-setup, you need to add it to this file:

```
/usr/share/ibus/component/simple.xml
```

But I still don't understand why you would need to use IBus at all.